# Object not loaded due to lazy loading. How to return all objects from BLL

Tags: linq, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, repository-pattern, unit-of-work

I'm having a bit of trouble figuring out how to make this repository pattern work.

In a nutshell, my solution looks something like this...

```
        ASP.Net MVC
             ^
             |
       Business Logic
             ^
             |
       Data Access 
(Repositories and Unit of Work)
             ^
             |
  Entity Framework Models
```

I have a Users table with a reference to a Roles table.

In my MVC app, I call the BLL with a GetAllUsers.  The code in the BLL looks like this:

```
public List<User> GetAllUsers()
{
    using (UnitOfWork uow = new UnitOfWork())
    {
        UserRepository userRepository = new UserRepository(uow);
        return userRepository.GetAll().ToList();
    }
}
```

The UserRepository derives from GenericRepository, which has a GetAll()

```
public class GenericRepository<T> : IGenericRepository<T> where T : class
{
    private IUnitOfWork _uow = null;

    public GenericRepository(IUnitOfWork uow)
    {
        _uow = uow;
    }

    public virtual IQueryable<T> GetAll()
    {
        return _uow.Set<T>().AsQueryable();
    }
}
```

It returns a list of users to my MVC app, but when I try and access the Role reference, it hasn't loaded yet due to lazy loading.

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    BusinessLogic.Account blAcct = new BusinessLogic.Account();
    List<User> users = blAcct.GetAllUsers();

    string firstName = users.FirstName;  // Works fine
    string role = users.Roles.RoleName;  // Fails because the context is closed.

    return View();
}
```

I've tried to put an .Include(Roles) on the GetAllUsers, but .Include isn't available on IQueryable.

Theoretically speaking, am I right in thinking that the MVC app shouldn't need to know anything about the context or the data access?
And second, how should I be including this Roles reference in my graph before it leaves the BLL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right in thinking your MVC application, *given your current application architecture*, should not be concerned with the `DataContext` and data retrieval.

A solution may be to add another `Repository` method that eagerly loads your `Roles`:

`public IList<Users> GetAllUsersWithRoles()`

Then selectively use the method that is appropriate, given the context.

Comment: I would gladly do this, but even my UserRepository is working with IQueryable and doesn't have access to the Context.  The context is completely controlled in the Unit of Work.  Perhaps I need to re-think how my UoW and repository is architechted.

Comment: You could expose the `DataContext` through the `UoW` class as a public property only using it during retrieval methods. Though this feels like a code smell.

Comment: Another option would be to have the repository take the base `DataContext` (through it's constructor) and have it injected using an `IoC container`. Only using this Context during `Retrieval` and not `Updating`, `Inserting` or `Deleting`

Comment: Yeah, I exposed it as a public property.  Now my UserRepository overrides all the get methods and .Includes the roles.  Works perfectly.  Except now my context is exposed for everyone. A friend method would be perfect here.  Sure wish C# had these...  I'll take a look at injecting the context.  That sounds like it might be a more OO friendly approach!  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I've been in these situations myself, where you want the code all 'nice and smug', but the abstraction doesn't let you control the  underlying implementation the way you want.

First, let's ask an important question: How likely is it that you will switch the OR/M you're using to another implementation?

If it is quite probably, and you really need the abstraction, then it depends on if the performance you lose in all lazy fetches is significant. Perhaps it's not a problem? Then I'd be OK with some N + 1 queries.

However, if the performance is not acceptable, you could try to add your own interface which includes the `Include` methods on your own `IQueryable`. Gets kind of ugly if you want a lot of the underlying functionality though.

To get around the closed session you could either move the session lifestyle to a higher level, or use more specific methods, returning DTO's. Then you don't have the problem of not knowing what is lazily loaded and what's not.